# How to access an object inside an array of array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to access to an object in side an array of array. Here is how my console.log showing:

```
0:
Memberships: Array(1)
0:
teamId: "5413e75f-ff12-4b7a-a3fe-f892cd006366"
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
Ratings: []
Skills: []
fullname: "Nhan Nguyen"
institution: ""
linkedin: ""
location: ""
major: ""
```

So now I want to get access to teamId which is inside an array of array, here is my following code:

```
{invitees?.map((user, index) => (
  <Grid item className="invitees-card" key={index}>
    {user.Memberships[0].teamId !== teamId && (
    <InviteCard tab={tab} user={user} />
    )}
  </Grid>
))}
```

it gave me `.teamId` is undefined which is I think my syntax is wrong but is there any way I can access to teamId without doing another mapping?

Comment: Looks correct from a quick glance, consider creating a [mcve] like codesandbox

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-rosalind-5m2vp @TJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the objects don't have a membership property so you should use a null safe operator: `user?.Membership[0]?.teamId`

Or do `user.Membership && user.Membership[0].teamId` to guard against `undefined`

Comment: How can I just show user that have the teamId is null ?

Comment: @nathan you want to display a list of such users?

Comment: Yes I want to display list of user that have different teamId or have not have teamId yet

Comment: @nathan something like `invitees.filter(user => !user.Membership)`

Comment: If I wrote like you it giving me no data back but If I wrote like this `.filter((userTeamId) => !userTeamId.Memberships?.teamId)` It send all the user include user already in the team